# How to configure Gradle dependencies when converting an app to a library for use in another app

Tags: android, gradle

For a number of inane reasons, I have to split an existing app into phone and tablet versions with multiple APKs (each one has nearly 100Mb of different static resources--yes, I'm mad at the guy who was in charge of requirements).

To achieve this, I am converting the original app into an Android library using `com.android.library` in the original package (and removing `applicationId` from `build.gradle`).

To import the library into my new app (`myProjectTablet`), I added the following to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':myProjectLib'
project (':myProjectLib').projectDir = new File('../myProjectRoot/myProjectLib')
```

To compile it, I added the following to `build.gradle`:

```
compile project (':myProjectLib')
```

For now, I need two apps based on this library so the directory structure is:

```
myProjectRoot
    myProjectLib
    myProjectPhone
    myProjectTablet
```

And to finally ask my question: I receive some variant of the following Gradle error no matter how I tweak paths and such:

```
Error:Project :tablet declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :lib.
```

From my searching, it seems this usually has to do with a conflict in using the `default` keyword in the context of certain libraries and tools, but I don't believe my apps have anything like that. If anybody has any insight into this error, I would appreciate it.

Comment: And after two days of messing this up, I finally realized that  
`project (':myProjectLib').projectDir = new File('../myProjectRoot/myProjectLib')`

needs to be:  

    `project (':myProjectLib').projectDir = new File('../myProjectLib')`

Answer (score 0):

And after two days of messing this up (and accidentally trying to put this in a comment), I finally realized that:

`project (':myProjectLib').projectDir = new File('../myProjectRoot/myProjectLib')`

needs to be:

```
`project (':myProjectLib').projectDir = new File('../myProjectLib')`
```

Gradle simply wasn't finding the project it seems.